# Make a GET request to a JSON file URL and store the response so it can be used globally on Vue.js application start?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Imagine the following scenario - I have a Vue.js component and I am trying to display the name of a user, however, I only have the ID of that user. I also have a JSON file URL that contains all user objects and each object contains the name and ID of the user. This way I could find the name of the user based on his ID.

Currently, I make a GET request for that JSON file when the Vue.js component is mounted and store the response when the GET request goes through. After that I can use the function which returns me the name of the user based on his ID.

Now the problems I have with this way of doing it is that:

- I make a GET request to the JSON file URL every time the component is reloaded
- I can only access the response from the GET request inside this component only. I will need to have access to the same JSON from different components as well and right now I'd have to make GET requests to the same JSON file from the different components which seems incorrect to me

I assume storing the JSON response in VUEX would be a good idea because I'd be able to access it from anywhere, however, I'm not sure from where should I make the GET request to the JSON file in this case.

Is there a place in Vue.js where I can put the GET request so that it gets executed every time the Vue.js application is started but no more than once?

Comment: so u are not making request to api endpoint, but rather to jaon file in your project? if so you could just import json file to vue component. Other way is to use keep-alive read it in docs

Comment: best way is not to use get request at all, because it will boost your performace a bit. Because if it is just a file, u could just import it... same way you do it with image etc.

Comment: as for your question where to make get request if you were to store it in vuex, it should be in vuex store itself, use actions... read docs to find out more

Comment: No it's not an API endpoint, it's just a JSON file. I have to make the GET request for that JSON because it changes very often.

Comment: then try using keep-alive or vuex, read vuex docs to see how to make get request in actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - Vuex is the way to go to solve this problem.

Assuming you're working in a vue-cli project, you can make that initial request in either

1. main.js
2. App.vue (Top level component, inside the created hook)

Either work, just make sure you commit the user info to Vuex after making the call.

I would recommend using App.vue because you could setup a spinner/loading icon while the user data is being loaded to show the user is app is 'doing something' if it takes a long time to load.